# execute an if statement on every folder

Tags: shell

I have for example 3 files (it could 1 or it could be 30) like this :

```
name_date1.tgz
name_date2.tgz
name_date3.tgz
```

When extracted it will look like :

```
name_date1/data/info/
name_date2/data/info/
name_date3/data/info/
```

Here how it looks inside each folder:

```
name_date1/data/info/
    you.log
    you.log.1.gz
    you.log.2.gz
    you.log.3.gz

name_date2/data/info/
    you.log


name_date3/data/info/
    you.log
    you.log.1.gz
    you.log.2.gz
```

What I want to do is concatenate all `you` file from each folder and concatenate one more time all the concatenated one to one single file.

1st step: extract all the folder

```
for a in *.tgz
do
a_dir=${a%.tgz}
mkdir $a_dir 2>/dev/null
tar -xvzf $a -C $a_dir >/dev/null
done
```

2nd step: executing an if statement on each folder available and cat everything

```
myarray=(`find */data/info/ -maxdepth 1 -name "you.log.*.gz"`)

ls -d */ | xargs -I {} bash -c "cd '{}' &&

if [ ${#myarray[@]} -gt 0 ];
then

find data/info -name "you.log.*.gz" -print0 | sort -z -rn -t. -k4 | xargs -0 zcat | cat - 
data/info/you.log > youfull1.log

else

cat - data/info/you.log > youfull1.log
fi "

cat */youfull1.log > youfull.log
```

My issue when I put multiple `name_date*.tgz`it gives me this error:

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
```

With the error, I still have all my files concatenated, but why error message ?

But when I put only one `.tgz` file then I don't have any issue regardless the number `you` file.

any suggestion please ?

Comment: Inside `"` quotes you need to escape `"` -> `\"`. [Do not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) and [do not use backticks \` use $(...)](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete). If you `xargs` with bash pass input as argument, for example `xargs -n1 bash -c 'echo "$1"' --`

Comment: `expr` is an artifact of the 1970s; any use of it is a code smell. `a_dir=${a%.tgz}` is far more efficient, and guaranteed to work on every shell compatible with the early-90s POSIX specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something simpler. No need for `myarray`. Pass files one at a time as they are inputted and decide what to do with them one at a time. Try:

```
find */data/info -type f -maxdepth 1 -name "you.log*" -print0 |
sort -z |
xargs -0 -n1 bash -c '
     if [[ "${1##*.}" == "gz" ]]; then
        zcat "$1";
     else
        cat "$1";
     fi
' --
```

If you have to iterate over directories, don't use `ls`, still use `find`.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'name_date*' -print0 |
sort -z |
while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do
   cat "$dir"/data/info/you.log
   find "$dir"/data/info -type f -maxdepth 1 -name 'you.log.*.gz' -print0 |
   sort -z -t'.' -n -k3 |
   xargs -r -0 zcat
done
```

or (if you have to) with xargs, which should give you the idea how it's used:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'name_date*' -print0 |
sort -z |
xargs -0 -n1 bash -c '
   cat "$1"/data/info/you.log
   find "$1"/data/info -type f -maxdepth 1 -name "you.log.*.gz" -print0 |
   sort -z -t"." -n -k3 |
   xargs -r -0 zcat
' --
```

Use `-t` option with `xargs` to see what it's doing.

Comment: Thank you I tried the 3rd option and I am getting the same error as my first code `gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file`. In my code, is there any reason I got this error message when putting multiple `.tgz` file ?

Comment: Is it intended that the last sample's `sort` doesn't have a `-z` on it?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, the file is not partially written, the weird part is if I put on single `*.tgz` file it will work nicely without error (and I tried with 10 different file individually), but altogether it gives the error.

Comment: I'm surprised you're still seeing the "partially written" comment -- I deleted it pretty much immediately after posting it, on seeing that the `sort` was missing a `-z` and so would munge the filenames.

Comment: ...the other possibility is that there *aren't* any filenames coming out of the `find | sort` pipeline, in which case `zcat` would be run with no arguments, which would also explain surprising behavior.

Comment: Added the `-n` to sort and added `-r` to `xargs` so it does not run if the input is empty.

Comment: @KamilCuk thank you, it works but there are 2 things : the output is not sorted but scrambled and I forgot the scenario (my mistake) where `you.log` doesn't exist.

Comment: So add a `if [[ -f "$dir"/data/info/you.log ]]; then cat ...; fi` and I do not understand _how_ the output should be sorted.